# Add Account with Android AccountManager

Tags: android, xamarin.android, accountmanager

I have a suite of apps and my `AccountManager` files live in one central app.  I can use `AccountManager.AddAccount()` in that central app, but when I try to use that method from the other apps, the `AuthenticatorActivity` is not started.  I  can debug and see that all of the code from `AddAccount` is being executed, but the activity is never launched.

Here is my `AddAccount` method:

```
public override Bundle AddAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, string accountType, string authTokenType, string[] requiredFeatures, Bundle options)
{
    var intent = new Intent(_context, typeof(MyAccountAuthenticatorActivity));
    intent.PutExtra(MyAccountAuthenticatorActivity.ARG_ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);
    intent.PutExtra(MyAccountAuthenticatorActivity.ARG_AUTH_TYPE, authTokenType);
    intent.PutExtra(MyAccountAuthenticatorActivity.ARG_IS_ADDING_NEW_ACCOUNT, true);
    intent.PutExtra(AccountManager.KeyAccountAuthenticatorResponse, response);

    var bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.PutParcelable(AccountManager.KeyIntent, intent);
    return bundle;
}
```

I use the same splash screen in all of my apps, so the code that calls AddAccount is the same.

```
            _accountManager = AccountManager.Get(this);
            var accounts = _accountManager.GetAccountsByType(AccountKeys.ACCOUNT_TYPE);

            //automatically add new account if no users on device yet
            if (accounts.Length == 0)
            {
                _accountManager.AddAccount(AccountKeys.ACCOUNT_TYPE, AccountKeys.AUTH_TYPE, null, null, this, null, null);
                CheckIfFirstRun();
                Finish();
            }
```

`MyAccountAuthenticatorActivity` is located in one app.  As you can see, I am sending in the correct activity context to `AddAccount` but `StartActivity()` is only called when those code is executed in the app that owns the authenticator files.

What else am I missing to allow my other apps to open up `MyAccountAuthenticatorActivity`?

Comment: Dear OP I am verry sorry for messing the Edits, to be honest the `xamarin.android` tag is relevant in your question, please do not remove it.

Comment: Ok, I will leave it.  But I can never seem to get help on questions tagged with Xamarin, and I am pretty sure the issue is AccountManager related and not Xamarin related.

Comment: Is there any error in your logs?

Comment: No errors at all.  It just doesn't launch MyAccountAuthenticatorActivity.  So the app just finishes.

Comment: I am guessing I need to put the service and that activity in the manifest of all of my apps too.  I also do not know how to do this though...tried to make things exactly like Udinic's example but it does not like me referencing a service that does not exist in the current app.  And there do not seem to be any Xamarin examples of a working AccountManager.

Comment: Yeah thats right, I just forgot to mention that thing. Also you should use the <full package name>.<Activity | Service name> in-order to reference it (That's how we do it in regular Android development, I am positive that it does the same in Xamarin).